# Are there European-style spas in Bangkok?

Tags: bangkok, spa

My partner and I love to visit spas and hot springs when we're in Europe. She enjoys getting massages, while I prefer to relax by reading a book or just soaking in the water. We're planning a trip to Thailand and we were wondering if there's something similar in Bangkok that's adapted, of course, to the local temperature. We don't expect there to be hot pools, but rather a kind of spa where I don't have to wait awkwardly in an uncomfortable chair while my partner gets a massage.

Just to clarify: I'm looking for places like Therme Erding where massages are complementary to the stay. Places where you can spend a whole day relaxing here and there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many spa's like that in Bangkok, even better ones than in Europe.

Try Divina Scentuara Spa in Bangkok; you do have to wait in some bath, though. (In which you can read your book)

Oh, and above all: It's pretty affordable. If you 'really' are looking for a pool, go for  Nitra Serenity Center, it's more expensive, but you will get two infinity pools for your money!

Comment: I have been browsing the Divina Scentuara Spa and Nitra Serenity Center website. I probably didn't explain myself properly. These are exclusive massage places where there are some bathing facilities. I am looking for places like Therme Erding where massages are complementary to the stay. Places where you can spend a whole day relaxing here and there.

Comment: That's difficult, Anantara Riverside Bangkok Resort might get close to this, there you have it all =)